# Table view cell elements not able to click and get data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one table view and inside that i placed one main view. And inside that main view i placed one button.And when ever use click on my cell button. I need to get the cell title label.This is what i need. But i tried following below code. Not sure what i am missing out. It not at all calling my cell.add target line.

Code in cell for row at index:

```
cell.cellBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.cellBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonPressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("cell tap")
    let button = sender as? UIButton
    let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! KMTrainingTableViewCell
    print(indexPath?.row)
    print(currentCell.cellTitleLabel.text)
}
```

I even added a breakpoint, still it not at calling my cell.addTarget line

Tried with closure too. In cell for row at index:

```
cell.tapCallback = {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

In my table view cell:

```
var tapCallback: (() -> Void)?
@IBAction func CellBtndidTap(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Right button is tapped")
    tapCallback?() 
}
```

Here that print statement is getting print in console.

Comment: use any one ...

Comment: i tried two solution differently only. Not at same time

Comment: why you're using AnyObject as parameter if its a UIButton?

Comment: okay,What should i need to pass exactly ? but even when i add break point to this ` cell.cellBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonPressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)` its not at all getting call

Comment: is this print this `print("cell tap")`, have you added the frame for your main view as well as ensure once are you enabled the userInteractionEnabled for your mainview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The added button is showing in table view for all the cell in my screen. And my main view is setted to userIntraction enabled in my storyboard under attribute inspector

Comment: `print("cell tap")`  is not printed

Comment: is this possible to attach your peoject

Comment: Use the callback, it's much more efficient and *swiftier* than this *view hierarchy math*

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik actually no, its an big project and i am doing in between of that

Comment: @David can you please post full code of tableview or possible attach screenshot of the cell . can you log in did select whether its working or not

Comment: @david  confirm from ur end that, in cell for row method, if you used any if or guard condition or any completion handler. And you added your line at out of these mentioned conditions. May be if you write inside it wont call.Like you mentioned you checked with breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var list = [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        cell.saveButton.tag = indexPath.row
        //cell.saveButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "some unique identifier"
        cell.tapCallback = { tag in
            print(tag)
        }
        return cell
    }
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!

    // MARK: - IBActions
    @IBAction func saveTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        tapCallback?(sender.tag)
    }

    // MARK: - Actions
    var tapCallback: ((Int) -> Void)?
}
```

Comment: Tags are pointless in this case. The index path is captured in the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a good programming practice to add the button (which contains in table view cell) target action in view controller. We should follow the protocol oriented approach for it. Please try to under stand the concept.

```
/*This is my cell Delegate*/
protocol InfoCellDelegate {
    func showItem(item:String)
}


/*This is my cell class*/
class InfoCell: UITableViewCell {
    //make weak reference to avoid the Retain Cycle
    fileprivate weak var delegate: InfoCellDelegate?

    //Outlet for views
    @IBOutlet var showButton: UIButton?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    //This is the public binding function which will bind the data & delegate to cell
    func bind(with: DataModel?, delegate: InfoCellDelegate?, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Now the bind the cell with data here
        //.....
        //Assign the delegate
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    //Button action
    @IBAction func rowSelected(sender: UIButton) {

        self.delegate?.showItem(item: "This is coming from cell")
    }
}


/*Now in your ViewController you need to just confirm the InfoCellDelegate & call the bind function*/
class ListViewController: UIViewController {
     //Views initialisation & other initial process
}

//Table view Delegate & Data source
extension ListViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    /**
    Configure the table views
    */
    func configureTable() {

        //for item table
        self.listTable.register(UINib.init(nibName: "\(InfoCell.classForCoder())", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "\(InfoCell.classForCoder())")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InfoCell") as! InfoCell

        cell.bind(with: DataModel, delegate: self, indexPath: indexPath)

        return cell
    }
}

extension ListViewController: InfoCellDelegate {
    func showItem(item) {
        print(item)
    }
}
```